# Javascript functions not working properly in LiveCycle PDF form

Tags: javascript, pdf, livecycle

I have a dynamic PDF XFA form created with LiveCycle that uses extensive Javascript.  It works great when I open it in Adobe Reader 11 but when I open it with Adobe Reader 10.01 the following code in a text field change event does not execute correctly:

```
if (xfa.event.newText.match(/[^0-9-:;,]/))

    xfa.event.change = "";

else

    if (xfa.event.newText.length > 0)

        xfa.resolveNode("this.ui.#textEdit.border.fill.color").value = "255,255,255";
```

any ideas?

Also the toUpperCase() function does not work.

Comment: *created with LiveCycle* - which version?

Comment: I now see that the toUpperCase function is not working either.  The following line of code still gives me a lowercase string: xfa.event.change = xfa.event.change.toUpperCase();